# Need Help Writing a Forecast SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a hard time coming up with a SQL query to provide a 6 month forecast. I can get my data into a pivot via query in the following format:

```
Period   Date                       Percent
-------------------------------------------
1        2013 11 01 00:00:00.000    0.3762  
2        2013 12 01 00:00:00.000    0.3584  
3        2014 01 01 00:00:00.000    0.3604  
4        2014 02 01 00:00:00.000    0.3292  
5        2014 03 01 00:00:00.000    0.3519  
6        2014 04 01 00:00:00.000    0.4064  
7        2014 05 01 00:00:00.000    0.3874  
8        2014 06 01 00:00:00.000    0.4067  
9        2014 07 01 00:00:00.000    0.4623  
10       2014 08 01 00:00:00.000    0.412  
11       2014 09 01 00:00:00.000    0.4155  
12       2014 10 01 00:00:00.000    0.3929  
13       2014 11 01 00:00:00.000    0.4038
```

I need to forecast the next 6 dates 12/1/2014 thru 5/1/2015 using the last 6 months in the data set (periods 8 thru 13)

```
Period    Date                       Percent       Forecast  
----------------------------------------------------------------
 1        2013 11 01 00:00:00.000    0.3762  
 2        2013 12 01 00:00:00.000    0.3584  
 3        2014 01 01 00:00:00.000    0.3604  
 4        2014 02 01 00:00:00.000    0.3292  
 5        2014 03 01 00:00:00.000    0.3519  
 6        2014 04 01 00:00:00.000    0.4064  
 7        2014 05 01 00:00:00.000    0.3874  
 8        2014 06 01 00:00:00.000    0.4067  
 9        2014 07 01 00:00:00.000    0.4623  
10        2014 08 01 00:00:00.000    0.412  
11        2014 09 01 00:00:00.000    0.4155  
12        2014 10 01 00:00:00.000    0.3929  
13        2014 11 01 00:00:00.000    0.4038     
14        2014 12 01 00:00:00.000                  0.3936  
15        2015 01 01 00:00:00.000                  0.3874  
16        2015 02 01 00:00:00.000                  0.3811  
17        2015 03 01 00:00:00.000                  0.3748  
18        2015 04 01 00:00:00.000                  0.3686  
19        2015 05 01 00:00:00.000                  0.3623
```

How do I do this?

Comment: This isn't something that databases are designed to do.  Use a statistics package -- SAS, SPSS, R, or something similar.

Comment: Were you given some business rules about how to derive the forecast from the data you have?

Comment: This is feeding an SSRS Chart, which is why I am not doing this in another tool. The only place I've ever done forecasting was in Excel using the FORECAST function. We are moving the reporting from Excel into SSRS and SQL Server.

Comment: Designing a forecast algorithm is too broad. This should be closed.

Comment: What's your forecast algorithm? To us, the forecast values starting on row 14 are just random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The values from row 14 on were generated by the Forecast function in Excel using the data in the table. In any case, I found the solution I needed here:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/69334/